# Как добавить inline клавиатуру в send_audio aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, inline

Нужна помощь в aiogram.
Нужно добавить INKB - inline keyboard в send_audio.
Вот код:

```
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor
from aiogram import Bot, types


storage = MemoryStorage()
bot = Bot(token="TOKEN")
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)


async def on_startup(_):
    register_hendlers_admin()
    print('bot started')    # Преднастройки


class FSMAdmin(StatesGroup):
    audio = State()


async def start_command(messege: types.Message):
    await messege.answer("Введите /upload или /up что бы загрузть трек")


async def process_upload_msic_command(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("Загрузите аудио")
    await FSMAdmin.audio.set()


async def load_audio(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    audio_id = message.audio.file_id
    await message.answer("Принял.")

    INKB = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3).add(InlineKeyboardButton(text="++"))\
        .add(InlineKeyboardButton(text="+-"))\
        .add(InlineKeyboardButton(text="--"))   # Эту инлайн-клаву нужно вкарячить в Send_audio

    await bot.send_audio(message.chat.id, audio_id, performer="Performer", title="Title")  # сюда
    await state.finish()


def register_hendlers_admin():
    dp.register_message_handler(start_command, commands=['start', 'help', 'h'])
    dp.register_message_handler(process_upload_msic_command, commands=['upload', 'up'])
    dp.register_message_handler(load_audio, content_types=['audio'], state=FSMAdmin.audio)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True, on_startup=on_startup)
```

Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем то я нашёл в чём проблема.
Я пропустил callback_data при создании кнопок и соотвецтвенно handler который должен их "улавливать"

Код:

```
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor
from aiogram import Bot, types


storage = MemoryStorage()
bot = Bot(token="5017752074:AAEXKaci10kn9WRVuo5HHYLkBJk4KxsxV1c")
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)


async def on_startup(_):
    register_hendlers_admin()
    print('bot started')    # Преднастройки


class FSMAdmin(StatesGroup):
    audio = State()


async def start_command(messege: types.Message):
    await messege.answer("Введите /upload или /up что бы загрузть трек")


async def process_upload_msic_command(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("Загрузите аудио")
    await FSMAdmin.audio.set()


async def load_audio(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    audio_id = message.audio.file_id
    await message.answer("Принял.")

    INKB = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3).add(InlineKeyboardButton(text="++", callback_data="++"))\
        .add(InlineKeyboardButton(text="+-", callback_data="+"))\
        .add(InlineKeyboardButton(text="--", callback_data="--"))   # Эту инлайн-клаву нужно вкарячить в Send_audio

    await bot.send_audio(message.chat.id, audio_id, performer="Performer", title="Title", reply_markup=INKB)  # сюда
    await state.finish()


async def call_back_data(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
    await callback.answer()


def register_hendlers_admin():
    dp.register_message_handler(start_command, commands=['start', 'help', 'h'])
    dp.register_message_handler(process_upload_msic_command, commands=['upload', 'up'])
    dp.register_message_handler(load_audio, content_types=['audio'], state=FSMAdmin.audio)
    dp.callback_query_handler(call_back_data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True, on_startup=on_startup)
```

Comment: Если у вас возникает новый вопрос то вам необходимо оформить его как вопрос и не использовать для этого ответ